# Using the HTTP status code parameter in HTTPPost and HTTPost2 AMPscript functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

According to the documentation for [HTTPPost](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httppost/) and [HTTPPost2](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httppost2/), you should be able to retrieve the **HTTP status code** from the response payload, but I can't seem to get this to work. I can only retrieve the response body. Here's a request that I've tried with both functions:

```js
%%[
var @httpPostCallStatus, @httpPost2CallStatus, @httpPost2Response
HTTPPost('https://httpbin.org/post', 'text/html', 'hello', @httpPostCallStatus)
HTTPPost2('https://httpbin.org/post', 'text/html', 'hello', true, @httpPost2CallStatus, @httpPost2Response)
]%%

HTTPPost call status: %%=v(@httpPostCallStatus)=%%

HTTPPost2 call status: %%=v(@httpPost2CallStatus)=%%

HTTPPost2 reponse: %%=v(@httpPost2Response)=%%
```

This returns the following:

```json
HTTPPost call status: {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "hello", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "5", 
    "Content-Type": "text/html", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Singularityheader": "appId=796*ctrlguid=1485623992*acctguid=c6f9028b-9792-49f7-a36f-01b2bd8101dc*btid=68226*guid=c4b32254-2d88-4188-8196-a3e17dde6485*exitguid=104*unresolvedexitid=0*cidfrom=251*etypeorder=HTTP*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][3609894]}"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "136.147.128.1", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

HTTPPost2 call status: {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "hello", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "5", 
    "Content-Type": "text/html", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Singularityheader": "appId=796*ctrlguid=1485623992*acctguid=c6f9028b-9792-49f7-a36f-01b2bd8101dc*btid=68226*guid=c4b32254-2d88-4188-8196-a3e17dde6485*exitguid=106*unresolvedexitid=0*cidfrom=251*etypeorder=HTTP*cidto={[UNRESOLVED][3609894]}"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "136.147.128.1", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}

HTTPPost2 reponse: System.Data.DataRow[]
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is the documentation simply incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the variable to get the HTTP status code from the response payload.

```
%%[ 
    SET @StatusCode = HTTPPost2('https://httpbin.org/post', 'text/html', 'hello', true, @httpPost2CallStatus, @httpPost2Response) 
  ]%%
 %%=v(@StatusCode)=%%
```

**Result:** 200

Also, you can get the status directly by running the HTTPPost2 function.

```
%%=HTTPPost2('https://httpbin.org/post', 'text/html', 'hello', true, @httpPost2CallStatus, @httpPost2Response)=%%
```

**Result:** 200

Comment: Thanks! It's bizzare that the examples provided in the HTTPost and HTTPost2 documentation don't set these functions as variables!